# Refering to columns from more tables having the same attribute name

Tags: javascript, sqlite, firefox-addon

When using *SQLite* database from *Javascript* you will use the following statement to get the *title* from database column of table *T*.

```
while (statement.executeStep())
{
  title = statement.row.title;
}
```

How would you refer to *title* if it originates from two tables *T1* and *T2*? Both of them have title attribute and in the *SQL* statement I use dot notation as follows:

```
select T1.title, T2.title from ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to give them different names on the SQL query:

```
SELECT T1.title as title1, T2.title as title2 FROM ...
```

Hope this helps.